# get values from a column based on first occurrences of numbers from a different column - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have matrices of this kind:

```
m = [randi(20,1,20)', [ones(1,3), ones(1,5)*2, ones(1,8)*3, ones(1,4)*4]']

ans =

     5     1
    19     1
     6     1
    16     2
     4     2
     6     2
     2     2
    12     2
    14     3
    11     3
     9     3
    13     3
    13     3
    14     3
    13     3
    19     3
     5     4
    15     4
     5     4
     3     4
```

Is there an efficient way to extract the values of `m(:,1)` that correspond to the first occurrence of each number of `m(:,2)`?
In my example that would be:

```
 ans =
    5   16   14   5
```

Comment: Look into `unique` function. Search for its documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the second column is sorted (as in your example):

```
m([true; diff(m(:,2))~=0],1)
```

Comment: +1.  Never considered the second column as a 1D signal.  Good use in differentiating and finding edges!

Comment: @Luis Mendo: Thank you, that works! What exactly is doing the "true" in this case?

Comment: @HappyPy With `diff` you look for differences, so you lose the first entry. That `true` just introduces that entry back. It should be `true` because you always want to select the first entry, as it is always a the first occurrence of a value

Answer (score 3):

Divakar is a boss!  In any case, you can use the `unique` function on the second column of your matrix that will tell you where the **first** occurrence is of the number you want.  Try doing this:

```
[~,index] = unique(m(:,2));
```

The first output parameter will be an array that eliminates all of the duplicates in `m(:,2)`, while `index` will tell you where the first occurrence of every unique element occurred.  We don't need the first parameter, which is why we have nulled it with `~`.

As such, `index` should thus be:

```
index = 
 1
 4
 9
17
```

Then you can access your values via: `m(index,1)`, which should thus give you:

```
 5
16
14
 5
```

Comment: Yes he is :-) And very generous too. His comment (slightly expanded) could have been an answer @Divakar

Comment: @LuisMendo: I agree.  He could have easily made it an answer... so thanks Divakar!

Comment: @LuisMendo It's just that I am sure that this has been covered before on `SO`, just lazy to find out!

Comment: @Divakar: Well I haven't seen it yet, so thanks for letting me answer!

Comment: @rayryeng +1 for expanding on the suggestion :)

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks for the good words BTW :) I learnt all these kool MATLAB tools from you guys on `SO`!

Comment: @Divakar Same here. A few months ago I didn't know about `bsxfun` or `accumarray`... can you imagine? :-D

Comment: @LuisMendo haha wow! That's a great knowledge gathering I must say, I mean `bsxfun` takes time! `S0` is great!!

Comment: @LuisMendo: Me too.  I didn't know about `bsxfun, cellfun, arrayfun, accumarray, col2im, im2col, colfilt....` until I started actively posting here a month ago.  Both you and Divakar are awesome!

Comment: @All, For me, I am getting into accumarray and cellfun and all those function handling stuffs. Its fun! Good luck guys!

Comment: @All: Take a look at @chappjc 's posts.  That's where I learned about `accumarray`.  He is a strong advocate for the function, and with very good reason too!

Comment: @LuisMendo Oh yeah, learnt all those `ismember`, even `unique` from him! I am still feeling for `accumarray` and `cellfun`, which seems to be quite useful and popular. Also his regex's were great!!

Comment: @Divakar: I think you were talking to me, but I'll let it slide ;)

Comment: @rayryeng haha no! Its All basically, but @ chappjc isn't that much active now. So the context was sort of ancient ;)

Comment: Pity that @chappjc is not very active these days, isn't it? Where are you? We miss you! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Well I felt like jumping in here and I had to come up with something, so here it is.

**Code**

```
binmat1 = bsxfun(@eq,m(:,2),min(m(:,2)):max(m(:,2)))
[~,ind] = max(binmat1(:,any(binmat1)))
out = m(ind)
```